# How can you setup a clojure project in eclipse so it will start when you click run?

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure

This is my first experience with Clojure but I know lisp and java, but am quickly getting fed-up with this REPL! I don't think it is too much to ask that when I click run, the application runs so I added a :main to my project.

```
(defproject Physics "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]  
  :aot [Physics.core]
  :main Physics.core
)
```

And this is what I now get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: -main in this context, compiling:(Physics/core.clj:19:3)
```

The application works fine before attempting to get it to autostart but after I added the :main directive to my project it broke, removing the :main directive doesn't help at all because I now get the same error. If I try to load the application manually from REPL it isn't found.

```
;; Clojure 1.5.1
=> (load "core")
FileNotFoundException Could not locate core__init.class or core.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

Restarting eclipse resolved this issue...

And here is the code located in src/Physics/core.clj (modified based on preliminary answers)

```
(ns Physics.core (:gen-class))

(declare -main)

(defn app-name []
  "Physics"
)

(defn version []
  "0.0.1-alpha"
)

(defn reload [] 
  (load "core")
  (load "config")
  (load "desktop")
)

(defn author []
  "Ralph Ritoch"
)

(defn author-email []
  "Ralph Ritoch <rritoch@gmail.com>"
)

(defn copyright []
  "Copyright \u00A9 2014 Ralph Ritoch. All rights reserved."
)

(defn banner []
  (println (str (app-name) " v" (version)))
  (println (copyright))
)

(defn restart []
  (reload)
  (-main)
)

(defn -main [& args]
  (ns Physics.core)
  (banner)
  (load "config")
  (load "desktop")
  (eval '(Physics.desktop/create))
)
```

The primary issue still remains. How do I get it to start when I click run? When I click run now all I get is a little green message that says #'Physics.core/-main but the application doesn't actually run.

Comment: Your main namespace must have a function called `-main`, which will be compiled into `public static void main`. You must also have the `(:genclass)` directive on the ns declaration, and you must ensure Ahead-of-Time compilation is performed on that ns (in project.clj, use `:aot`). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

1. There should be a `-main` function in `ns` `Physics.core`
2. `=> (load "core")` directly looks for `core.clj` in the `src` folder. You should use `(load "Physics/core")` instead.
3. `(defn restart []
     (reload)
     (-main)
   )`
   Here, you should write `(declare -main)` before this form

Comment: You could have at least Read the question first. And you were wrong on both counts. => (load "Physics.core")
FileNotFoundException Could not locate Physics.core__init.class or Physics.core.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: My fault, it's `(load "Physics/core")`.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, but the issue just changed when I tried that. => (load "Physics/core")
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: -main in this context, compiling:(Physics/core.clj:19:3)

Comment: There should be a -main function in ns Physics.core

Comment: I don't know whats so unclear about this... (defn -main [& args]
  (banner)
  (Physics.desktop/create)
) ... It is right in the question... I have defined the -main

Comment: Your experience with other LISPs shows here, and it interferes with your attempts at Clojure. Relevant to your case, Clojure does not support forward references, unless explicitly declared with `(declare)`. The compilation unit in Clojure is not the file, but a single `(defn)` form.

Comment: Is there a clean/rebuild or some equivalent? Something is obviously broken since all functionality is broken.

Comment: There is no clean/rebuild since the only clean way to do it is restarting the whole REPL.

Comment: @Marko following your "suggestion" of my coding style I deleted everything in core and replaced it with (ns Physics.core)

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "foo")
) But i'm still getting the same -main not found.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, finally got it

Comment: I have yet to make a single comment on your coding style. I did comment on your *asking* style, however.

Comment: And don't use Uppercase letter in project names, that's also a convention

Comment: Now you are completely unclear as to what exactly steps you took. You replaced the contents of a file, then what? Have you also started over by deleting the previous Run configuration? How exactly do you create the Run configuration? Have you made it work from the command line first? All you give us is your frustration.

Comment: I restarted eclipse and now everything is working properly again, though I do need to change some things about how everything loads as I'm now getting runtime exceptions. The runtime environment somehow got corrupted.

Comment: I resolved the loader problems but I still am back to the original problem. It doesn't start when I click run. I need to type (ns Physics.core) and then (-main). I'll gladly accept this answer when that issue is resolved.

Comment: I don't have eclipse at hand. Can you edit your post to show your changes of code?

Comment: @Albus, I have altered the code. Using qualified names "Physics/desktop" ... doesn't work since the code is always run from the Physics namespace/folder, the code that is there is functional if I change the namespace and run the -main function from REPL manually.

Comment: I also just added the namespace switch to Physics.core so it can be run from any namespace. But when I click run all I see is a green message saying #'Physics.core/-main , but it isn't running unless I manually start it.

Comment: I still don't see any mention of your attempt to add `(:genclass)` to the ns declaration and `:aot` to `project.clj`. Without that you don't get a regular Java class which the Java runtime can load and run.

Comment: @Marko, I'm fairly sure that is part of the issue, but I added it and still no auto-run.

Comment: @Marko, I found A solution, even if I don't like it... I added -m Physics.core to the Run configuration and it is now autostarting as I intended. I also resolved all compile errors with lein.

Comment: I guess then you're starting it as a leiningen runnable? My goal was making it work as a plain Java Run Configuration.

Comment: @Marko, my primary goal was simply to get it to run when I click run. After compiling with lein I saw all the classes in the target folder so its clear the code needs restructuring. I'm not accepting my answer because as you suggest, there is a better way, I just can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

From the eclipse main menu select **Run > Run Configurations** and then select or create a clojure run configuration and click the **(x) = Arguments** tab, and set the **Program arguments:** to the following.

```
-m Physics.core
```

Replace **Physics.core** with the namespace containing the -main defn

Note: This may not be the best solution, but it works.